# WU-FTPD install failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install wu-ftpd 2.6.0 on my ubuntu machine.  I have run the ./build lnx command and now when I run the ./build install command I get the following error:

No rule to make target 'bin/ftpd', needed by 'install'. Stop.

Can anybody help me with what is wrong?

I have seen that the dir bin/ftpd does not exist.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: Have you read the README for that package? Maybe you need to run something like ./build ftpd.

Comment: Tried that, same error...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see , this package is available in pre-compiled format, so why are you trying to build it from scratch? On my Ubuntu box (10.04) I can install 2.6.2 from synaptic. That would save you a lot of headaches.